# Try to upload an image into firebase storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

i'm trying to upload and image from a device to firebase storage but i don't know which format i should use. i've try with put and putString, but both of them gave me invalid argument.

This is the code to pick and upload the image.

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    if (!image) {
      Alert.alert(
        'You have to choose an image first'
      );
    } else {
      const uri = image;
      console.log(uri);
      const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
      setUploading(true);
      setTransferred(0);
      const task = firebase.storage()
        .ref(filename)
        .put(uploadUri);
      // set progress state
      task.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
        setTransferred(
          Math.round(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 10000
        );
      });
      try {
        await task;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
      setUploading(false);
      Alert.alert(
        'Photo uploaded!',
        'Your photo has been uploaded to Firebase Cloud Storage!'
      );
      setImage(null);
      }
};
```

This is the uri of the image (the console.log output) : [image]

This is the error using .put(uploadUri):

[image]

This is the error using .putString(uploadUri, 'data_url') :

[image]

Comment: In the future don't post images of textual content please, but instead post the actual text. That not only makes your question more searchable, but also allows us to more easily use that error message to search for related questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+storage+invalid+argument+in+put+at+index+0

Answer (score 2):

In order to upload an image on Firebase storage using `put` you need to pass a `blob` as param instead of `string`.

For example you can do something like this:

```js
import path from 'path'

const uid = 'image-id'
const fileName = uid + path.extname(uri)
const response = await fetch(uri)
const blob = await response.blob()


const uploadImage = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .put(blob, {
        contentType: `image/${path.extname(uri).split('.').pop()}`
      })

uploadImage.on(
      'state_changed',
      snapshot => {
        // progress
      },
      err => {
        // error
      },
      () => {
        // complete
      }
```

Comment: I tryed to do like you said but can't find variable path

Comment: @vale1234ntina123 sorry, I've updated my answer with the correct import. You need to add the `path` module to your `package.json`